# function doesn't call from one class to another class in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in react js, so i appologies for this type of error, here i have created 2 class, Test1 and Test2, I want to call `function_two` function from class 1, but it doesn't working, can anyone please help me for this issue, here is my full code for that

```
class Test1 extends React.Component {
    function_one() {
        <Test2 function_two={this.function_two} />
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <h1>{this.function_one}</h1>
        );
    }
}

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  function_two() {
      return "Funtion 2";
  }
}

//CallCRUD

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test1 />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There are various methods for doing this. Do you want to pass state-data from `Test2` to `Test1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things :

1. You forgot to call your function : `this.function_one` should be `this.function_one()`
2. You did not return anything in `function_one` (you forgot the return statement)

Working fix :

```js
class Test1 extends React.Component {

 function_two(origin) {
  console.log('Hello, from ' + origin)
 }

 function_one() {
  return <Test2 function_two={this.function_two} />
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <h1>{this.function_one()}</h1>
  );
 }
}

class Test2 extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
  this.props.function_two('Test2')
 }
  
  render = () => <div/>
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Test1 />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

EDIT :

If your objective is to simply render something in your `h1` tag you could do the following :

```js
class Test1 extends React.Component {

 function_one() {
  return <Test2/>
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <h1>{this.function_one()}</h1>
  );
 }
}

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  
  render(){
    return <div>Hi, I'm Test2</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Test1 />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

Shorter syntax :

```js
const Test1 = () => <h1><Test2/></h1>

const Test2 = () => <div>Hi, I'm Test2</div>

ReactDOM.render(
 <Test1 />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't we call function_two()  from Test2 class ?

Comment: Th function is called in Test2 in the code I gave you, `this.props.function_two('Test2')` calls it

Comment: Thanks,i can see in console.log it is working, but when i just return that string, it doesn't print in <h1> tag, can you please help me for this